# Moving wordpress site from hosting to localhost for development

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

After moving website to my local dev machine, relative links stopped working.  When i click button with relative link /login, for example, browser redirects to

https://localhost/login/

and shows

> Code: Not Found
>
> The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

While it should have redirected to [https://localhost/сс/login/](https://localhost/%D1%81%D1%81/login/)

*.htaccess* contents on *localhost*:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cc/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /cc/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

1. Website files are in *var/lib/html/cc* folder.
2. *SiteURL* and *HomeUrl*
   are both equal to [http://localhost/сс](http://localhost/%D1%81%D1%81)
3. Parmalinks setting *http://localhost/cc/sample-post/* is used, so no problem with navigating to pages.

How to fix this issue?

Tried different *.htaccess* modifications, moving *index.php* to */var/lib*
Nothing helps.

Comment: is WP_SITEURL or WP_HOME set in wp_config.php?

Comment: no, in wp-admin/DB

Comment: if you are developing a theme, why not just create a new wordpress site on your local machine from scratch and simply copy the theme over. Or migrate the databases only if you need the data. Usually the simplest solution and saves time.

Comment: Can you try once by resetting permalink to default and than setting it again to default value?

Answer (score 0):

just use WP Migrate DB plugin for database export , it will change all link to your desire link and use this database export file in live site

Link ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/)